# Get day of week name based on aribitary starting day (Not always Sunday)

Tags: php

I know in PHP I can use the `date` function to get the name of the day of week. However, the problem that I ran into is with a weather API that returns 5 days of weather starting with TODAY as the first position in the array.

I have it working with the below code, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner method.

The below code slices the array from the new start day to the end of the array, then splices the beginning of the array off then merges them back together.

The first argument passed to the function is the arbitrary start of the week and the second is the day of the "new week" that I'm attempting to get.

```
function get_day_name($start, $get_day){
        $days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        $array_start = array_slice($days,$start);
        $array_end = array_splice($days,0,$start);

        $days = array_merge($array_start,$array_end);

        return $days[$get_day];
    }

echo get_day_name(date("w"), 0);
```

Comment: you could use `date("l")` for the current day, and `date("l", strtotime("+1 day"))` for the next, etc.

Comment: How about just `return $days[$get_day + $start % 7];` and declaring the array `$days` as static?

Comment: @Dharman I get  `Undefined offset` errors. When passing 5 as the start day (Friday) and 2 as the day that I want. So Friday would become 0 and Sunday would be the position returned.

Comment: My bad, order of operations... put brackets on addition.`($get_day + $start) % 7`

Comment: @spielerds that works (for the first day I'm just using the same code so it comes out to be +0 day but that doesn't cause an error. if you add that as answer I will accept

Comment: @imvain2 it's done, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `date("l")` for the current day, and `date("l", strtotime("+1 day"))` for the next, etc.

or with objects `(new \DateTime())->format('l')` for the current, and `(new \DateTime('+1 day'))->format('l')` for the next, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about date why not use it?

```
$dayOfWeek = date("l", strtotime($dateHere));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `\Datetime` library and current locale to display the name of the weekday.
Using [`l` as a format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you can the weekday starting from Sunday.

Just pass the date string into the constructor and then call the `format` method on the object created. This is a better solution than `strtotime` as it handles Dates with better precision and correctness.

```
$dayOfWeek = (new \DateTime($dateString))->format('l');
```